# python plot non linear equation

Tags: python, plot, nonlinear-functions

What is the easiest way to plot a non linear equation in python.

For example:

```
0 = sqrt((-6 - x) ** 2 + (4 - y) ** 2) - sqrt((1 - x) ** 2 + y ** 2) - 5
```

I would like to plot that equation for `x in [0, 10]` and look like a continuous curve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way to plot implicit equations by using numpy+matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
from numpy import arange, meshgrid, sqrt

delta = 0.025
x, y = meshgrid(
    arange(0, 10, delta),
    arange(0, 10, delta)
)

matplotlib.pyplot.contour(
    x, y,
    sqrt((-6 - x) ** 2 + (4 - y) ** 2) - sqrt((1 - x) ** 2 + y ** 2) - 5,
    [0]
)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Output:

[image]

This method is really handy to analize closed forms, for instance, a circle of radius 3 would look like:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.contour(
    x, y,
    x**2+y**2-9,
    [0]
)
```

[image]

Comment: THANKS!! this is exatly what i need. Only one doubt, what is the `[0]` refers to?

Comment: @9uzman7 No problem, try this to understand... `contour(x, y, x**2+y**2-9)` , `contour(x, y, x**2+y**2-9, [0])`, `contour(x, y, x**2+y**2-9, [0, 10, 20])`. Hope that helps ;)